# How do i draw a ball when a button is pressed?

Tags: c#, winforms

in my game i have the following code

```
private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
    {
        paper = e.Graphics;
        paddle.drawPaddle(paper);
        ball.drawBall(paper);
        bricks.drawBricks(paper);
    }
```

What i want is so that when i click a button the ball is drawn, but only when i click the button, so i want to place the drawball in this part of the code

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

how do i do this because as far as im aware you only draw the ball under "form paint"

Comment: This question is missing context. Is this a Winforms project? Add tags to specify the type of project this is related to. C# isn't the issue here, the issue is how to get the "Graphics" when it isn't passed to your event. You could, however, store it in a private field on the paint event, the use it later.

Comment: @DannyVarod I don't think those events exist outside of winforms (though it *was* missing the tag). Since I know its winforms (from previous questions) I've added the tag for him. Also, please don't put tags in titles

Comment: What do you mean by "draw when pressed"? If you draw on the click event, the next `Paint` to come through will just erase it. Could you be more specific about the behavior you are looking for? By the way, this question is *much* better than your previous ones, thank you for working on your writing!

Comment: Set a boolean in the button click, then call `Invalidate` to trigger a repaint. Check the boolean in the Paint method and draw the ball or don't.

Comment: If the problem is fixed, you can note that be accepting the answer that solved it for you (or helped the most). If *none* of the answers did that; consider posting your own answer (make sure its up to the sites standards of course).

Comment: You can do a `control.CreateGraphics();` and draw graphics from any method. However, I'm a firm believer of doing all my graphics from my paint event. Therefore, your best answer is Eldar's answer.

Answer (score 2):

Add a special flag for storing your ball's visibility:

```
private bool _isVisible = false;

private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
{
    paper = e.Graphics;
    paddle.drawPaddle(paper);
    if (_isVisible)
    {
         ball.drawBall(paper);
    }
    bricks.drawBricks(paper);
}

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _isVisible = true;
    // Now you need to invalidate the form to get it repainted
    Refresh();
}
```

Comment: Thanks thats exaclty what i needed! :)

Comment: @BradleyDotNET this is basically what i need ^^ but iv just realised that the ball still moves before the button is pressed, and when the button is pressed it just makes the ball visible, which causes the problem if i start the program and press the button after 3 or more seconds then the ball will already reach the bottom of the form and the player will lose a life